# Consulta en 2 tablas con condiciones en 1

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo 2 tablas:
En la primera (A) los siguientes datos:

```
TABLA-A
nombre      fecha     estado
==============================
 Ariel        12         2
 Pablo        X          1
```

Segunda tabla (B)

```
TABLA-B
nombre      deporte
=======================
Ariel       Futbol
Pablo       Basquet
```

Necesito que consulte sobre la primera tabla quien tiene fecha = X y estado = 1, pero a la vez saber el deporte correspondiente a este desde la otra tabla.

El resultado seria:

```
RESULTADO
nombre      fecha     estado    deporte
=========================================
Pablo         X          1      Basquet
```

Estuve probando con Inner Join. Se que debe ser facil pero algo me esta trabando. Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Un buena manera de ayudarte mas rapidamente es compartir el codigo que tienes, para ver donde te estas atorando, podrias editar la pregunta y poner tu codigo

Comment: ¿Porque no utilizaste una relación? Con campo PRIMARY KEY y FK

Comment: Bienvendio creo que buscas es [yahoo respuestas](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/) y esto es `stackoverflow` un sito creado para que los desarrolladores pueden encontrar soluciones a problemas de programación en diferentes lenguajes